# deployed clickonce application not working in client system

Tags: c#, installation

I created a c# windows application and deployed it by clicking publish(clickonce). now 2 setup files and a Application folder are generated. when the setup file is installed in one system in which it was created, it is working properly. but when i copy the files to another system and install, when i run the icon nothing happens. what to do?also how to add mdf or ldf files  to the setup file?

Answer (score 0):

The idea with publishing a ClickOnce application is not to copy it elsewhere afterwards but to execute the installer from the publish location.

Otherwise you'll need to change the app location in the manifest using [MageUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for instance.